# Shuffling a LinkedList while maintaining a structure

Tags: java, list, shuffle

I have a `LinkedList` stored in the form `[1a,1b,2a,2b,3a,3b, etc.]` and I would like to shuffle it so that the `#a` and `#b` stay together. I know that you can make an object which holds both `#a` and `#b` then shuffle a `LinkedList` of those objects but I was wondering if there is a more convenient way to do it.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: There's a more *inconvenient* way of doing it, manually.

Comment: please add in your question what would be the expected result concretly

Comment: No, what you suggested is the most convenient way. If you want to use [`Collections.shuffle()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-) (*by far* the most convenient way) and you want to keep `1a` and `1b` together, then you need an object of the values to keep together, and shuffle those objects.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 streams may be the most convenient way.

Here is example code, run 10 times to see effect of [`shuffle()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-).

```
List<String> input = Arrays.asList("1a","1b","2a","2b","3a","3b");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    List<List<String>> tmp = new ArrayList<>(input.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.substring(0,1)))
            .values());
    Collections.shuffle(tmp);
    LinkedList<String> output = tmp.stream()
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
    System.out.println("\t" + output);
}
```

*Output*

```
[1a, 1b, 2a, 2b, 3a, 3b]
[2a, 2b, 3a, 3b, 1a, 1b]
[3a, 3b, 1a, 1b, 2a, 2b]
[1a, 1b, 2a, 2b, 3a, 3b]
[3a, 3b, 1a, 1b, 2a, 2b]
[1a, 1b, 2a, 2b, 3a, 3b]
[2a, 2b, 3a, 3b, 1a, 1b]
[3a, 3b, 2a, 2b, 1a, 1b]
[1a, 1b, 2a, 2b, 3a, 3b]
[1a, 1b, 3a, 3b, 2a, 2b]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. You are using the word "shuffle" to actually sort the entries #a and #b stay together. If what my assumption is right you can achieve it by using `java.util.Collections.sort()` so that you can pass your customised Comparator implementation class to sort function. 
One such example on how you could achieve it is given below.

```
class LinkedListSort{

     public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
        String linkedListDataString = "1a,1b,2a,2b,3a,3b";
        for(String str : linkedListDataString.split(",")) {
           list.add(str);
        }

        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String object1, String object2) {
                String suffix1 = object1.substring(object1.length()-1);
                String suffix2 = object2.substring(object2.length()-1);

                return Collator.getInstance().compare(suffix1,suffix2);
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Sorted list entries: ");
        for(String e:list) {
        System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```